# I cant use phpdoc [Could not open input file: \phpdoc.php]

Tags: php, phpdoc

I downloaded phpdoc, and whatever I do, he drops:

`Could not open input file: \phpdoc.php`

in the console. The path of this file is in the path and php include's path. I did tried him with another php script and it confirmed that (from console).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install phpdoc? Please provide the full command you use to launch it.

Comment: I just downloaded https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/zipball/develop and extracted to a directory

Comment: and I just tried phpdoc.bat, nothing else

Comment: Is a problem solved in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404506/phpdocumentor-could-not-open-input-file-phpdoc-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following the approach suggested on the [main page](http://www.phpdoc.org/):

```
$ pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
$ pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor-alpha
$ phpdoc -d . -t docs
```

Comment: I dont have pear. I dont even want to use it, I think it just would create more problems

Comment: Its purpose is to let you install php packages easily) try it. Otherwise check that your php installation works in cli mode properly, check include paths. For example, what does 'php -v' show you?

Comment: "The XSL writer was unable to find your XSLTProcessor; please check if you have installed the PHP XSL extension"

Comment: well have you installed the PHP XSL extension)? It is not part of phpDoc, it is part of php.... Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404506/phpdocumentor-could-not-open-input-file-phpdoc-php